# Merging files within the Azrue Data Lake container

Tags: pyspark, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

Consider below scenario:

I want my data flow like following
import container ---> databricks (Transform)--> export container

**Current situation after I am done with the transformation process
container:**

```
---import
    --folder
        --mydata.csv
---export
    --folder
        --part-1-transformed-mydata.csv
        --part-2-transformed-mydata.csv
        --part-3-transformed-mydata.csv
        --initial.txt
        --success.txt
        --finish.txt
```

**I want below structure:**

```
---import
    --folder
        --mydata.csv
---export
    --folder
        --transformed-mydata.csv
```

What should be preferred way (considering data is of few GBs <10) within data-bricks or I am happy to use any functionality in Data Factory as I am using this data-bricks notebook as a step in pipeline .

**Note** : I am using Apache Spark 3.0.0, Scala 2.12 in data-bricks with 14 GB Memory, 4 Cores. Cluster type is standard

Answer (score 0):

you will either need to repartition the data into a single partition (note this defeats the point of using a distributed computing platform)

or after the files are generated simply run a command to concat them all into a single file this might be problematic if each file has a header you will need to account for that in your logic.

it might be better to think of the export folder as the "file" if that makes sense. doesn't solve your problem but unless you need to produce a single file for some reason most consumer wont have an issue reading the data in a directory